# An R function for writing a tex file to folder

Tags: knitr

Is there a function in R that will allow me to write a latex code for tables with a .tex name file to a folder. Or simply just like we have a write.csv function that can write a table of dataset to a folder, with a .csv extension. Is there a similar function such as write.tex that can write or convert my latex code of a table into a file with a .tex extension to a folder ?

Answer (score 4):

```
library(xtable)
a <- matrix(c(1,2,3,444,5,6,7,8,9),nrow=3)
b <- print(xtable(a))
write(b,file="test.tex")
```

This produce:

```
% latex table generated in R 3.6.1 by xtable 1.8-3 package
% Mon Nov 25 22:13:48 2019
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{rrrr}
  \hline
 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\ 
  \hline
1 & 1.00 & 444.00 & 7.00 \\ 
  2 & 2.00 & 5.00 & 8.00 \\ 
  3 & 3.00 & 6.00 & 9.00 \\ 
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

But there are not need to go to R, write the table and then include in a LaTeX file. Just compile a `.Rnw` file:

```
% Test.Rnw 
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
<<mytable,echo=FALSE,results='asis'>>=
library(xtable)
a <- matrix(c(1,2,3,444,5,6,7,8,9),nrow=3)
b <- print(xtable(a))
@
\end{document}
```

When edited with Rstudio, simply click the "Compile PDF" button. Or from the command line:

```
Rscript -e "library(knitr); knit('Test.Rnw')"
pdflatex Test.tex
```

Comment: It works for me now, I had not critically looked at it. The write function does the job. Thanks very much.